# second motor won't stop unless I disconnect power

Tags: gpiozero

I am using an L298N board and two pi yellow pi servos and a program on my pi to control everything:

```
# Driving One Motor Using GpioZeo and L298N v0.01  tlfong01  2019jun11hkt1156
# rpi3B+ python 3.5.3 gpiozero 1.5.0 L298N
# wiring -  GPIO17, GPIO18, GPIO2, GPIO3, GND
# Equipment: Raspberry Pi, 4AA pwr src, pi motor 1, pi motor 2, 5 pi wires
# https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/build-a-buggy/3

from time import sleep
from gpiozero import Motor

motor = Motor(17, 18)
motor2 = Motor(2, 3)

motor.forward()
motor2.forward()
sleep(2)
motor.backward()
motor2.backward()
sleep(2)
motor.reverse
motor2.reverse
sleep(2)
motor.stop()
motor.stop()
```

the first motor starts, reverses and stops, but the second motor starts, reverses and then continues running until I remove the power.  I added the declaration of 'motor2' and all of the motor2 commands to the working program for a single motor from tlfong01, I guess I adapted this program incorrectly.  What is wrong with the code that is making the second motor run forever?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that the second line should read `motor2.stop()`:

```
motor.stop()
motor.stop() # <-- change to motor2.stop()
```

Comment: yea it was just that little typo.  Thanks I'll read the code a little more closely next time